# Unable to print Japanese characters fetched from MySQL using MyBatis

Tags: mysql, mybatis, ibatis

The collation of the column is set to "utf8mb4_general_ci". The data stored under that column is "ベッドルーム". But when I fetch this using MyBatis, and printed it out, the result is "????????\u2030?????????"

my config is this:

```
<property name="driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
<property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://domain:port/mydb" />
<property name="username" value="user"/>
<property name="password" value="pass"/>
```

Then I added character encoding to the url.

```
<property name="driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
<property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://domain:port/mydb?useUnicode=yes&amp;characterEncoding=utf8" />
<property name="username" value="user"/>
<property name="password" value="pass"/>
```

The result became this "??????".

I also tried adding the property driver.encoding

```
<property name="driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
<property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://domain:port/mydb" />
<property name="driver.encoding" value="UTF-8" />
<property name="username" value="user"/>
<property name="password" value="pass"/>
```

Still not able to print out the characters. I don't know where the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the problem was due to default encoding of Java. I just changed it upon startup of the program with the following code:

```
try 
{
    Field charset = Charset.class.getDeclaredField("defaultCharset");
    charset.setAccessible(true);
    charset.set(null,null);

    System.setProperty("file.encoding","UTF-8");
} 

catch (Exception e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```